# Open a local file in user's folder

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to open Chrome's Preferences file, a JSON text file in Chrome's folder on a Windows installation.

The thing is that I need to know the username to get the actual path.

Is there a way to acces a file in the user's folders tree without prompting for it, and without running any out of browser code?

I tried to use file:// protocol to access a relative path, but it seems file:// relative paths don't work on Windows.

Thank you

Comment: No. It's not possible to do that.

Comment: Thank you.  Any basis for that comment?